# Apache redirect path to root

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I am trying to redirect http://example.com/* to http://example.com/ but everytime I end up with a redirect loop. What is a incorrect on this? None of these two (or any other combinations of regular expressions) works:

```
RedirectMatch temp ^/.+$ http://example.com
RedirectMatch temp ^/.+$ http://example.com/
```

This is always matched and a redirect loop is being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want anything not the absolute root on `example.com` to temporarily redirect to `example.com`.  If so, I would suggest you try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=307]
```

Or perhaps this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=307,NC,L]
```

**EDIT:** If you need to add a trailing slash to the URL, you can do this; using my second example above:

```
# Settings for adding a trailing slash to the URL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ / [R=307,NC,L]
```

Also, [this site has a nice/concise explanation](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/website-and-server-administration-forum/236611-redirectmatch-v-rewriterule-what-best-practice.html#post1215405) of what the difference is between `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite).

Comment: That works, but I need to add a slash on the beginning, so it is RewriteRule ^/.+$ / [R=307,NC,L]. But I don't understand, why RedirectMatch is not working as expected.

Comment: `RedirectMatch` uses `mod_alias while `RewriteRule` uses `mod_rewrite.` Since `mod_alias` just creates a simple alias, the server will loop since you are aliasing an alias to the same place you started. While `mod_rewrite` actually does regex matching to allow for subtleties as you describe. Will edit answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectMatch temp (example.com)/.*$ $1/`

Comment: Not working too. Seems that nothing is matched. http://example.com/xxx does not redirects to http://example.com/